# Oracle SQL - Subquery vs Order By Fetch first 1 row only

Tags: sql, oracle

| ID | REF_NO | NAME | SALARY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dummy1 | Smith | 5487 |
| 2 | Dummy2 | Tim | 3123 |
| 3 | Dummy1 | Smith | 432424 |
| 4 | Dummy4 | Steve | 99577 |
| 5 | Dummy5 | Matt | 5551444 |
| 6 | Dummy2 | Tim | 432112 |
| 7 | Dummy7 | Brad | 89897 |
| 8 | Dummy3 | Kevin | 123213 |
| 9 | Dummy3 | Kevin | 7878 |
| 10 | Dummy3 | Kevin | 43555 |
| 11 | Dummy2 | Tim | 432 |
| 12 | Dummy8 | Jerry | 32123 |
| 13 | Dummy8 | Jerry | 43434 |
| 14 | Dummy9 | Gayle | 8989897 |
| 15 | Dummy2 | Tim | 1234 |
| 16 | Dummy6 | Jeff | 8989987 |
| 17 | Dummy1 | Smith | 545453 |
| 18 | Dummy2 | Tim | 6464 |
| 19 | Dummy2 | Tim | 43535 |
| 20 | Dummy1 | Smith | 64643 |
| 21 | Dummy8 | Jerry | 995 |

I have above data in my table, Which query is more efficient to fetch the data faster. My required data is get `Salary` of `Dummy2` where `Id` is maximum i.e. latest salary for Dummy2.

NOTE : This is an audit table having data more than 5 millions.

Query1 :

```sql
select a.Name,
       a.Salary
from   table a
where  a.REF_NO = 'Dummy2'
and    a.ID = (select max(id) from table where REF_NO = a.REF_NO)
```

Query2 :

```sql
select Name,
       Salary
from   table
where  REF_NO = 'Dummy2'
order by ID desc
fetch first row only
```

Comment: "Which query is more efficient to fetch the data faster?" - run them both, *many times*, and compare result you get. For a small data set, you won't notice any difference so you should test on LARGE data set. Otherwise, it just doesn't matter, pick the one you prefer.

Comment: I am asking for large data, consider this table as an audit table having data of 2 million

Comment: run an explain plan

Answer (score 0):

They are different queries and, assuming that you can have duplicate `id`s, will produce different results so you cannot easily compare them.

```sql
SELECT Name,
       Salary
FROM   table_name
WHERE  ref_no = 'Dummy2'
ORDER BY id DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

Would return, at most, a single row even if there are duplicate `id`s.

---

You can implement the query:

```sql
SELECT Name,
       Salary
FROM   table_name
WHERE  ref_no = 'Dummy2'
AND    id = (SELECT max(id) FROM table_name WHERE ref_no = a.ref_no)
```

as:

```sql
SELECT Name,
       Salary
FROM   table_name
WHERE  ref_no = 'Dummy2'
ORDER BY id DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

And will return as many rows as there are duplicate latest `id`s for the given `ref_no`.

Comment: column 'ID' cannot be same, That column is auto incremented, REF_NO can be same.

Answer (score 0):

Query 1 and Query 2 both gives same results, But Query 2 is more efficient than Query 1.
Reason is that the cost of query 1 more because of subquery inside it.

Comment: Not so sure about this. We should see the explain-plan. Yet, to be sure, just run both queries and see the performance.

Answer (score 0):

**[EDIT, as MT0 suggested - a brand new table with unique ID values]**

(Code I previously posted is still accessible behind *Edited* link)

---

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE test
  2  (
  3     id            NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  4     object_name   VARCHAR2 (200)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE INDEX ui1_test
  2     ON test (id);

Index created.

SQL> BEGIN
  2     FOR i IN 1 .. 100
  3     LOOP
  4        INSERT INTO test (object_name)
  5           SELECT object_name FROM all_objects;
  6     END LOOP;
  7  END;
  8  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT COUNT (*) FROM test;

  COUNT(*)
----------
   5814300
```

(OK, 5.8 million is far from 3.3 billion I used earlier, but is also almost triple as the OP mentioned (2 million))

Table contents:

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2    FROM test
  3   WHERE ROWNUM <= 5;

        ID OBJECT_NAME
---------- ------------------------------
         1 ORA$BASE
         2 DUAL
         3 DUAL
         4 MAP_OBJECT
         5 SYSTEM_PRIVILEGE_MAP
```

Let's now compare:

```
SQL> SET TIMING ON
SQL> SELECT id
  2    FROM test
  3   WHERE id = (SELECT MAX (id) FROM test);

        ID
----------
   5814300

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
SQL>   SELECT id
  2      FROM test
  3  ORDER BY id DESC
  4     FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;

        ID
----------
   5814300

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
SQL>
```

No difference (I ran it several times).

As I previously commented, you can't expect any difference on small data sets, and 2 (or 6) million isn't much.

Comment: The OP has stated that the `id` is unique so your queries are not comparing the same things as the first query will only ever return 1 row but the second query will return 58,000 rows for your sample data as you have duplicate ids.

Comment: OK; I modified the 2nd query so that it returns only one row as well, but - still no difference. `fetch first row only` returned result in a matter of *seconds*, another (`max(object_id)`) is still running.

Comment: The methodology you are using is still wrong as the updated second query is still not the same as the OP's query as the OP does not use `MAX` twice; so, while your experimental results are a useful indicator for your queries, they are not useful for the OP's queries as the queries are doing different things. If you want to compare like-for-like then create a table and insert your 3 billion rows with auto-incremented unique ids and then query that table for both the OP's queries.

Comment: I tried to follow what you said, @MT0; I hope I did it right. Well, no difference as far as performance is concerned on such a small (5.8 million rows) data set. Didn't feel like creating table with 3 billion rows.